# How do I add space between my dataset and the top of the graph in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I need to add more space between the top of the visible graph and the dataMax. Here's a visual example to make it clear. [image]

Now, I understand that I can add more space here by changing the max in yAxis such as

```
 yAxis: {
        max: 15,000
    }
```

,

However, the data comes from the backend, so the max needs to be set dynamically. I tried doing it in the render function, but the chart didn't adjust like it was supposed to. I found this odd. If you take a look at this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5ogw7phx/ , you'll see in the render function, I set the max to 2x the dataMax. This should give me a max of 5*2=10 on the graph, yet the top line remains at 6, not 10. Yet when I hardcode the yAxis to 10, it works fine as you'll see in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5ogw7phx/1/ How do I add extra space at the top of the chart without hardcoding a max? I'm also open to any solution with padding or spacing that doesn't have to do with maxes. I just need more whitespace.

Comment: Can't you use [`marginTop`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginTop) or [`spacingTop`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.spacingTop) chart options?

Comment: @kikon I can't, because I have three chart:{marginTop: ...} or chart:{spacingTop: ...} would only apply to the graph that's on top. I have three different graphs in my example and I'm trying to increase space in the middle one.

Comment: I don't know how you stacked your graphs; it would be interesting to see if there are no direct options solutions. Your fiddle example is lacking a redraw of the chart; the method [redraw](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#redraw) can be invoked, but *not in the render handler* because it leads to infinite recursion. It can be invoked in [load](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load)  (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2pstr4h/)) or even in an event related to loading of data if it comes through an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

To apply changes on a chart, it is not enough to set `this.yAxis[0].max = this.yAxis[0].dataMax*2;`

You need to call [update](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update) or [setExtremes](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes) axis methods. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cn2m876v/)

However, it is better to use `maxPadding` property. For example:

```
yAxis: {
  maxPadding: 0.5
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/knth0dpe/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.maxPadding